# Multiple Concatenation Column into One Column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, multiple-columns

We had been doing for the FIRST IN and LAST OUT of the Employees with the specified format for the Payroll System. 
Here is the format of the FIRST IN and LAST OUT.

> HS64000701180622I

HS64 - The first four digits indicates for the Employee Number.

00 - represents for the space between employee number and date of firstin and lastout

070118 - it represents for the date of firstin and

0622I - represents for the time in of the employee with an letter I indicator for the system to read that this format is for FIRSTIN entry data

> HS64000701181438O

while this format is for the LASTOUT of the employees showed that the same format of FIRSTIN but the difference is the time of lastout of employee shown "1438O" which indicates that the employee is out at the time of 2:38PM with an letter O indicator for the LASTOUT.

So, we have a query to show the result of the data.
Here is the query:

```
select  
    CONCAT(UID1FirstName,'00', 
    FORMAT(LogDate, 'MMddyy'),
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, FIRSTIN, 108), ':',''),'I') as FIRSTIN,
    CONCAT(UID1FirstName,'00', 
    FORMAT(LogDate, 'MMddyy'),
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, LASTOUT, 108), ':',''),'O') as LASTOUT from 
(
select 
        CAST(dtDate as DATE) as LogDate,
        MIN(CASE when ReaderName like '%ENTRY%' then FORMAT(dtDate, 'HHmm') END) as FIRSTIN,
        MAX(CASE when ReaderName like '%EXIT%' then FORMAT(dtDate, 'HHmm') END) as LASTOUT, UID1FirstName       
from Log_Transactions
        inner join UserCredentials on UID1 = CredentialId
        inner join UserDefinedFields on HostUserId = UserID
where 
        FieldNo = 1
        and Event = '2000' /*ACCESS GRANTED*/
        and dtDate between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-03' /*FOR SPECIFIC DATE AND TIME ONLY*/
group by
        CAST(dtDate as DATE), CredentialId, UID1FirstName, UID1LastName, Value
) as DT;
```

And here is the result of the query:

[SEE QUERY RESULT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVDHf.png)

Problem is the query shown above are in two columns. What is the best way to do for the query will be show into ONE column only.
Like this sample:

```
FIRSTIN AND LASTOUT
HS64000701180622I
HS64000701181438O
```

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.

Answer (score 0):

@Jev, to solve your issue, I will create a new format:

[image]

What you are doing is appending the First In time between, I: IXXXXI and Last Out betweet O's: OXXXXO.

```
HS64 - The first four digits indicates for the Employee Number.

00 - represents for the space between employee number and date of firstin and lastout

070118 - it represents for the date of firstin and

I0622I - represents for the time in of the employee with an letter I indicator for the system to read that this format is for FIRSTIN entry data

O1438O - will represents for the time in of the employee with an letter O LASTOUT
```

Your query will be modified as :

Let me know how it goes.

```
select  
    CONCAT(UID1FirstName,'00', 
    FORMAT(LogDate, 'MMddyy'),
    'I'+REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, FIRSTIN, 108), ':',''),'I')+
    'O'+REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, LASTOUT, 108), ':',''),'O') as FIRSTINLASTOUT from 
(
select 
        CAST(dtDate as DATE) as LogDate,
        MIN(CASE when ReaderName like '%ENTRY%' then FORMAT(dtDate, 'HHmm') END) as FIRSTIN,
        MAX(CASE when ReaderName like '%EXIT%' then FORMAT(dtDate, 'HHmm') END) as LASTOUT, UID1FirstName       
from Log_Transactions
        inner join UserCredentials on UID1 = CredentialId
        inner join UserDefinedFields on HostUserId = UserID
where 
        FieldNo = 1
        and Event = '2000' /*ACCESS GRANTED*/
        and dtDate between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-03' /*FOR SPECIFIC DATE AND TIME ONLY*/
group by
        CAST(dtDate as DATE), CredentialId, UID1FirstName, UID1LastName, Value
) as DT;
```